# How to access asp.net mvc route values in GetVaryByCustomString?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, outputcache

I'm running an asp.net mvc 2 site under .NET 3.5 and I'd like to have access to routing values in my `GetVaryByCustomString` handler in Global.asax. I'm unclear how (if at all) to access specific route values given the `HttpContext` passed to the function.

For reference, here is the signature of `GetVaryByCustomString`

```
public override string GetVaryByCustomString(HttpContext context, string custom)
{
    // how do I get at route values here from context?
}
```

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var routeData = ((MvcHandler)httpContext.Handler).RequestContext.RouteData;

var routeValues = routeData.Values;
var matchedRouteBase = routeData.Route;
var matchedRoute = matchedRouteBase as Route
```

Comment: This does not work on ASP.MET MVC 4 onwards, httpContext.Handler is always null, any solution around that?

Answer (score 6):

For anybody trying to make this work on ASP.NET MVC 4.0 onward, this is the correct way.

```
 HttpContextBase currentContext = new HttpContextWrapper(context);
 RouteData routeData = RouteTable.Routes.GetRouteData(currentContext);
```

This is a bit of hack, but this is the only solution at this moment, because caching validation is performed before routing, so route data is not available.

Answer (score -1):

Here's an easier way

```
httpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext.RouteData
```

Comment: This doesn't work any more with ASP.Net 4.5 (I don't know if it changed behavior or if this has never worked)
After generating the page, the RouteData is populated but then next time the page is hit it isn't populate...it checks the cache status BEFORE doing the routing.